# Sum of the series $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{e^{in x}}{(n+\alpha)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Here $\alpha $ is a non-integer real number. The series is apparently uniformly convergent and periodic.

Is it possible to find a closed expression of it?

Comment: A non-integer but in $\Bbb C$? Or just in $\Bbb R$? Also, is $x$ supposed to be $\alpha$?

Comment: It depends what you call closed form. Are you asking if somebody has already given a name to this series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $c \in (0,2\pi)$ then 
$$f(z) =e^{icz}\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}-i c e^{icz}\frac{2i\pi}{e^{2i\pi z}-1}- \sum_n \frac{e^{icn}}{(z-n)^2}$$ is entire and bounded thus constant. Since $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(-ix) = 0$ then $f(z)=0$.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on how you obtained $e^{icz}\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}-ice^{icz}\frac{2i\pi}{e^{2i\pi z}-1}$?  Thanks!

Comment: @Zvi The poles of $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$ are $\frac{1}{(z+n)^2}$, the poles of $\frac{1}{e^{2i \pi z}-1}$ are $\frac{1}{z+n}$. The poles of $h(z)\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$ are $\frac{h(n)}{(z+n)^2}+\frac{h'(n)}{z+n}$

Comment: I meant $z-n$ ${}{}$

Answer (score 3):

The function is related to the [Lerch zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function). In particular,
$$L\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}, \alpha,2\right) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{in x}}{(n+\alpha)^2}.$$

Thus, we have that
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}  \frac{e^{in x}}{(n+\alpha)^2}=L\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}, \alpha,2\right) + L\left(-\frac{x}{2\pi}, \alpha,2\right)- \frac{1}{\alpha^2}\,.$$